# Array of selected checkbox is not in sequence using post method

Tags: php, html

I wanted to get an array of all the checkboxes whether selected or not in sequence with the help of the PHP post method. I am getting an array but it shows on selected checkboxes first then the non selected ones. For me, the sequence is very important as this has to be used for Attendance. I am providing the code and output below.

**Code:**

```
<form action="aattendscr.php" method="post">
...
<td>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" class="switch_1" name="attendo[]">
   </div>  
</td>
</form>
```

aattendscr.php

```
<?php
 include "database.php";
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
    for($x=0;$x<count($data);$x++)
        {
            if(isset($_POST['attendo'][$x])){echo "On";}else{echo "Off";}
        }

    }
?>
```

**INPUT**

[image]

**OUTPUT**
On On On Off Off

**Desired Output**
On Off On Off On

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is `$data`? During submit look at `print_r($_POST['attendo']);` and present it here

Comment: It is an array storing the of details of student of a particular class.                    
Array ( [0] => on [1] => on [2] => on )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work around this you need to manually number the checkboxes in your form i.e.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="switch_1" name="attendo[0]">
<input type="checkbox" class="switch_1" name="attendo[1]">
...
<input type="checkbox" class="switch_1" name="attendo[n]">
```

This will force the assigned entries to be set (if the checkbox is checked) in `$_POST['attendo']`.

Answer (score 0):

use [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reindex an array

$array = array_values($array);